# read a direct message when arrival using telegram_api

Tags: telegram, telethon, telegram-api

i am working with an app and it needs to read direct messages from telegram when they arrive.

i searched on google but all i got was how to send a message not how to read brand new dms.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telethon: Make sure you read the basics [in the Docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/updates.html) to understand how to handle events.

I'm assuming you meant "mark as read", if not, read the docs, else read below:

in the event object you get to your callback, you have multiple unique convenience methods, and all the ones available on a [`Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.mark_read) object, one of them is event.mark_read()

to limit it only to send read requests to private chats; configure handler as needed, a minimal example:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def read_it_callback(event):
    await event.mark_read()
```

you can also use client.[`send_read_acknowledge()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_read_acknowledge)